# meaning of `STRING_ELT` in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I searched the source code of RCPP but could not find out the definition of STRING_ELT, could someone point to a reference where I could find all the definitions of the Macro like things in RCPP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of *R*'s internals accessed via:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
```

See [5.9.7 Handling character data](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Handling-character-data) of [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html):

> R character vectors are stored as STRSXPs, a vector type like VECSXP
>   where every element is of type CHARSXP. The CHARSXP elements of
>   STRSXPs are accessed using STRING_ELT and SET_STRING_ELT.
>
> CHARSXPs are read-only objects and must never be modified. In
>   particular, the C-style string contained in a CHARSXP should be
>   treated as read-only and for this reason the CHAR function used to
>   access the character data of a CHARSXP returns (const char *) (this
>   also allows compilers to issue warnings about improper use). Since
>   CHARSXPs are immutable, the same CHARSXP can be shared by any STRSXP
>   needing an element representing the same string. R maintains a global
>   cache of CHARSXPs so that there is only ever one CHARSXP representing
>   a given string in memory.
>
> You can obtain a CHARSXP by calling mkChar and providing a
>   nul-terminated C-style string. This function will return a
>   pre-existing CHARSXP if one with a matching string already exists,
>   otherwise it will create a new one and add it to the cache before
>   returning it to you. The variant mkCharLen can be used to create a
>   CHARSXP from part of a buffer and will ensure null-termination.
>
> Note that R character strings are restricted to 2^31 - 1 bytes, and
>   hence so should the input to mkChar be (C allows longer strings on
>   64-bit platforms).

Comment: thanks! Do you also know what does ELT mean or stand for ? because there are also  SET_VECTOR_ELT

Comment: Sets vector elements.

Comment: So, as far as I understand, `STRING_ELT` returns a number which is a pointer to a memory location in the global string cache which contains C-style string. `CHAR` returns the C-style string itself, type `const char *`, from the pointer given by the given by `STRING_ELT`.